# Drawing PDF from two views

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiview

I have first view `firstView` and also draw second view `secondView` and add it as the subview to `firstView`.
Also I have the method that creates from `firstView` PDF file:

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)firstView
{

    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, self.view.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    [firstView.layer drawInContext:pdfContext];

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"resolution.pdf"];

    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

How can I draw one PDF from this two views, so the PDF file must include at one page firstView and secondView

**Added**

In ViewController in `loadView` method

```
        AWFirstView *firstView = [[AWFirstView alloc] init];
    self.view = firstView;

    self.secondView = [[AWSecondtView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 300., 300.)];
    [self.secondView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

     self.createPDFButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.createPDFButton.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 88., 50.);
    [self.createPDFButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.createPDFButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createPDF) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self updateView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.drawWindow];
    [self.view addSubview:self.createPDFButton];
```

In updateView is something like this:

```
    -(void)updateView
{
    if(![self isViewLoaded])
        return;

    [[AWServices services].uiContext updateObjectInCurrentContext:&_resolution];


    AWFirstView *view = (AWFirstView *)self.view;
    view.post = _resolution.contact.officialPersonPost;
    view.name = _resolution.contact.officialPersonFullname;

    [view.superview setNeedsDisplay];
```

In

```
-(void)createPDF{
[self createPDFfromUIView:self.view];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I added

```
[self.secondView.layer drawInContext:pdfContext];
```

in `-(void)createPDFfromUIView` and it worked. But is this right solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, firstView.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[firstView.layer drawInContext:pdfContext];
```

Notice that I am now sending `drawInContext:` to `firstView`, as opposed to `myView` as you were doing. If `firstView` is passed in to the method, then this should give the expected result.

EDIT: You are not adding `secondView` as subview; do like this (third line):

```
self.secondView = [[AWSecondtView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 300., 300.)];
[self.secondView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.firstView addSubview:self.secondView];
```

Furthermore, that assignment you are doing to `self.view` does not really look good:

```
self.view = firstView;
```

Either you do:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.firstView];
```

or you define [`loadView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView) in your view controller and assign there to `self.view`.

Comment: it saves only firstView

Comment: if secondView is a subview of firstView, it should be also saved in the same PDF. can you show how you create firstView, secondView and how you make the latter a subview of the former?

Comment: I've added it, but it doesn't help me. I pass in `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, self.firstView.bounds, nil);` firstView that is in @property I also pass it in `[self.firstView.layer drawInContext:pdfContext];` so I don't pass even it in `-(void)createPDF{
[self createPDFfromUIView]` method anymore. If I check self.firstView.subviews it displays me secondView as subview